# Ubuntu systemd service for pygame

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, pygame, systemd

I have written a simple code with python and pygame to display some images at my monitor. When I run it, everything works fine. i tried to make it run at system startup with systemd services. here is my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts pygame

[Service]
User=rplab
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/myuser/MyPygame.sh
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the system boots, it will start the service but unfortunately when I checked the service with systemd status, it gives this error:

```
pygame.error: No available video device
```

it seems as if it starts too soon that can't find my monitor, is it possible that I make the service start after the user logs in so that it can find my monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service file needs to tell `systemd` that it needs to start after user-session and graphical environment.

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts pygame
Wants=systemd-logind.service systemd-user-sessions.service display-manager.service
After=systemd-logind.service systemd-user-sessions.service display-manager.service

[Service]
....
....

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Make sure you are running a `graphical.target` as the default.

```
$ systemctl set-default graphical.target
```